# How to render more multiple html pages in a single html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one main html called `main.html` . Inside that I want to show 3 html pages.Structure will be like this:

```
<mainhtml>    
      <create or edithtml/>
      <viewhtml/>
      <filterhtml/>
<\mainhtml>
```

filter html will be showed by default. when I click create button in filter page.Then filter page will be toggled and create page will be showed.

How can I render multiple htmls in a single html?I dont want to use `<iframe>` here

Comment: seems html tags are work, or not closed...

Comment: This question isn't specific enough, and doesn't really show that any attempt was made to actually code up a solution.  I would take a look at a tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) and then come back when you have **specific ** questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, there are two ways to show HTML content in AngularJs.

1. [UI-Router](https://ui-router.github.io/), and inside `main.html` page add 3 placeholders and show each page of the pages you want inside one of the placeholders.
2. Using [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) and include the pages as fixed included content.

P.S:
With `ngInclude` you can use `ngIf` to show and hide content depending on a specific condition.

Comment: I gave like this `<div ng-include="'UserList.html'"></div>` but page is not displaying.If I directly change in url means its working fine.

Comment: Try put the full URL in `ng-include` attribute, maybe the path to your html is not correct.